# How can I enable video autoplay in WKWebView on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I have a WebView that contains an iframe (an HTML element). this iframe has a Peertube video plyaer, I pass `&autoplay=1` to that iframe and it works good on android, iPad and browser, but on iPhone the video can not be autoplayed.

I tried custom render with WKWebView with this code:

```
class FullScreenEnabledWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
{
    WKUserContentController userController;

    public FullScreenEnabledWebViewRenderer() : this(new WKWebViewConfiguration() { MediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypes.None, AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true, MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false, RequiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = false })
    {
    }

    public FullScreenEnabledWebViewRenderer(WKWebViewConfiguration config) : base(config)
    {
        config.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
        config.AllowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true;
        config.AllowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true;
        config.MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = true;
        config.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
        config.RequiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = false;
        config.MediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypes.None;
    }
}
```

and still does not work.
Can you help me with that please.

Answer (score 0):

Webview in iOS couldn't support `iframe` very well . So it could better to use `<video>` like

```
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();

htmlSource.Html = @"<html><body><video width='300' height='500' muted='muted' controls autoplay='autoplay'><source src='https://ia800201.us.archive.org/12/items/BigBuckBunny_328/BigBuckBunny_512kb.mp4'  type='video/mp4'></video></body></html>";

webview.Source = htmlSource;
```

If it still could not auto play in iOS , we could invoked JS to play it  .

```
using System;


using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using App4;
using App4.iOS;
using WebKit;
using ObjCRuntime;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(FullScreenEnabledWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App4.iOS
{
    public class FullScreenEnabledWebViewRenderer: ViewRenderer<WebView, WKWebView>
    {
        WKWebView wkWebView;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();

                config.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
                config.AllowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = true;
                config.AllowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true;
                config.MediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = true;
                config.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false;
                config.RequiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = false;
                config.MediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypes.None;

                wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                wkWebView.NavigationDelegate = new WkWebviewPolicy();
                SetNativeControl(wkWebView);
            }


        }
    }


    public class WkWebviewPolicy : WKNavigationDelegate
    {

        public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, WKWebpagePreferences preferences, [BlockProxy(typeof(NIDActionArity2V120))] Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy, WKWebpagePreferences> decisionHandler)
        {
            decisionHandler.Invoke(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow, preferences);
            //base.DecidePolicy(webView, navigationAction, preferences, decisionHandler);
        }

        public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
        {
            base.DidFinishNavigation(webView, navigation);

            var JSstr =  @"var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video'); for (var i = videos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { var ivideo = videos[i]; ivideo.setAttribute('webkit-playsinline','\'); ivideo.play(); };";

            webView.EvaluateJavaScript(JSstr,null);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much man about your time, but I am so sorry, it does not work for me because I AM FORCED to use iframe, the video url can not be getten, I hav a url to html page that show the video as an embed video.